# PUT dictionary in dictionary in Python requests

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I want to send a PUT request with the following data structure:

```
{ body : { version: integer, file_id: string }}
```

Here is the client code:

```
def check_id():
    id = request.form['id']
    res = logic.is_id_valid(id)

    file_uuid = request.form['file_id']
    url = 'http://localhost:8050/firmwares'
    r = requests.put(url = url, data = {'body' : {'version': id, 'file_id': str(file_uuid)}})
```

Here is the server code:

```
api.add_resource(resources.FirmwareNewVerUpload, '/firmwares')

class FirmwareNewVerUpload(rest.Resource):
    def put(self):
        try:
            args = parser.parse_args()
        except:
            print traceback.format_exc()

        print 'data: ', str(args['body']), ' type: ', type(args['body'])

        return
```

The server prints:

```
data:  version  type:  <type 'unicode'>
```

And this result is not what I want. Instead of inner dictionary I got a string with name of one dictionary key. If I change 'version' to 'ver'

```
    r = requests.put(url = url, data = {'body' : {'ver': id, 'file_id': str(file_uuid)}})
```

server prints

```
data:  ver  type:  <type 'unicode'>
```

How to send a dictionary with inner dictionary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `json=` instead of `data=` when doing `requests.put` and `headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}`:

```
 r = requests.put(url = url, 
                 json = {'body' : {'version': id, 'file_id': str(file_uuid)}}, 
                 headers = {'content-type':'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 0):

In official doc you found a topic called [More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

> There are many times that you want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data will be posted directly.

```
>>> import json

>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Maybe convert your data to JSON could be a good approach.

```
import json

def check_id():
    id = request.form['id']
    res = logic.is_id_valid(id)

    file_uuid = request.form['file_id']
    url = 'http://localhost:8050/firmwares'
    payload = {'body' : {'version': id, 'file_id': str(file_uuid)}}
    r = requests.put(url=url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: Yes, this approach is working but I want to understand data location in POST and PUT requests. I did not find Dictionary limitations in documentations.

Comment: The limitation is not about the dictionaries. it's data here is to map a key x value as a param=value from HTTP request.

Comment: Does it means that parameters in location "data" can have only basic types?

Comment: Exactly what you found!