# FastAPI pytest with arguments

Tags: pytest, fastapi

I try to test fastAPI get route with pytest and the problem is how i can pass params to `client.get`

main.py

```
@app.get('/purpose'):
async def read_purpose(name, date):
    """some logic"""
    return {'ok':'ok'}
```

test.py

```
 client = TestClient(app)
 def test_purpose():
     response = client.get("/purpose", json={"name":"test_name", "date":"01.01.2020"})
     assert response.status_code = 200
```

My test is failed. it can not find `name`, and `date` arguments.

How i can pass this arguments to my test.

Thank you

Comment: This should be a GET request with query parameters, so replace `json=` with `params=` are you should be good to go. `json=` is for payload on POST/PUT/PATCH requests on resources that accept `application/json` as content type.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem when writing pytest for my first FastAPI demo.

```py
@router.post('/item', tags=['items'], response_model=ShowItem)
async def create_item(item: ItemCreate,
                      user_id: int,
                      db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    date_posted = datetime.now().date()
    # owner_id = 1
    item = Items(**item.dict(),
                 date_posted=date_posted,
                 owner_id=user_id)
    db.add(item)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(item)
    return item
```

You can try "params" instead of "json", because you are passing isolated query parameters

```py
def test_create_item():
    # wrong
    data = {'title': 'Hot Boat', 'description': 'This is a boat', 'user_id': 1}
    resp = client.post('/item', json.dumps(data))
    
    # correct
    data = {'title': 'Hot Boat', 'description': 'This is a boat'}
    resp = client.post('/item', json.dumps(data), params={"user_id": 2})
    
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Then i can by pass above error.

Try this fix:

```py
client = TestClient(app)

def test_purpose():
    response = client.get("/purpose", params={"name":"test_name", "date":"01.01.2020"})
    assert response.status_code = 200
```

More detail refer [Question 61383179](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383179/fastapi-passing-json-in-get-request-via-testclient)